# Add a new field in virtuemart new product form

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

I want to add a new field in virtuemart new product form, how can i do that ?

I add:

var $is_act = 1;
in "components\com_virtuemart\tables\products.php"

And

```
<?php echo  VmHTML::checkbox('is_act', $this->product->is_act); ?>
```

And in database but what is appear is a checkbox without a string behind it, what is the wrong ?!

Answer (score 1):

The `VMHTL::checkbox` function just create a check box without strings.

If you want to add string behind it you have to do something like this.

```
<?php echo JText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_IS_ACT') ?>

<?php echo  VmHTML::checkbox('is_act', $this->product->is_act); ?>
```

And then `COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_IS_ACT` should be added inside language file too.

for more clearness just check VM default `product_edit_information.php` page inside

```
administrator/components/com_virtuemart/views/product/tmpl/
```

Hope its helps..